# How to scroll to a widget inside the SingleChildScrollView in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, scroll, flutter-web

I'm working on a flutter web project.

When the user taps on an item, I need the main SingleChildScrollView to scroll down to the specific widget.

How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

To scroll to a specific widget you mainly need 2 things:

1- The position of your target widget. This can be achieved by getting the **RenderBox** of the widget (you will need to reference it with a GlobalKey first).

2- A **ScrollController** assigned to your SingleChildScrollView.

In the following sample you will find 3 buttons that scrolls the main SingleChildScrollView vertically (I've also tested it in web and it works).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  ScrollController scrollController;
  GlobalKey _keyGreen = GlobalKey();
  GlobalKey _keyOrange = GlobalKey();
  GlobalKey _keyIndigo = GlobalKey();
  double _containerHeight = 400;

  @override
  void initState() {
    scrollController = ScrollController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: scrollController,
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Offset _offset = _getPositions(_keyGreen);
                        scrollController.animateTo(_offset.dy, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
                      },
                      child: Text("Go green"),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Offset _offset = _getPositions(_keyOrange);
                        scrollController.animateTo(_offset.dy, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
                      },
                      child: Text("Go orange"),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Offset _offset = _getPositions(_keyIndigo);
                        scrollController.animateTo(_offset.dy, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
                      },
                      child: Text("Go indigo"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.lightBlue,
                  height: _containerHeight,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  height: _containerHeight,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.lightGreen,
                  height: _containerHeight,
                  key: _keyGreen,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  height: _containerHeight,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  height: _containerHeight,
                  key: _keyOrange,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                  height: _containerHeight,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.pink,
                  height: _containerHeight,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.indigoAccent,
                  height: _containerHeight,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.indigo,
                  height: _containerHeight,
                  key: _keyIndigo,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
  }

  Offset _getPositions(GlobalKey key) {
    RenderBox renderBoxRed = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    renderBoxRed.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    return renderBoxRed.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
  }

}
```

Comment: too complex, better check `Scrollable.ensureVisible` static method

Comment: Yes, thats a good option too. I didn't know about it.

Comment: @pskink , why don't you write an answer about that? With a short code example!

Comment: @RodrigoCardozo, your answer seems outdated... Doesn't work with null safety, and the types seem to have changed.  Could you make an update?